# How can I delete Account with Opportunities(Closed Won) via REST API?

Tags: rest-api, opportunity, account

As a documentation said when I delete a record all referal records will be deleted. But there are limitation about opportunities with Close Won Stage. If I change Opportunities to another Stage, Opportunities will be in that Stage after restoration.
How can I delete Account and preserve Opportunity Stage after restoration from Recycle Bin?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to dispose of the opportunities (open up the close opportunities) or delete them first and then delete the account.

Comment: How did SF delete account? It ask about delete "Closed Won" opportunities and if you said "OK" it deletes Account and all the stuff in it. When you resotre from Recycle Account appears with Opportunities.

Comment: That is SF and their UI, AFAIK, there is no option in apex to indicate that you want to delete won opportunities when deleting accounts. Not everything that SF can do can be done as simply by the developer.....